# How to activate more than one router in backbone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, coffeescript, url-routing

I am working on a Backbone UI for a rails app.  The app has four models, and they are all assigned a rectangular pane on the index page.  When I do the following to initiate all 4 routers:

```
window.BbTest =
  Models: {}
  Collections: {}
  Views: {}
  Routers: {}

initialize: -> 
  # alert "Hello from Backbone"
  window.WaterManagers_router =  new window.WaterManagersRouter()
  window.Valves_router =  new window.ValvesRouter()
  window.Histories_router = new window.HistoriesRouter()
  window.Sprinkles_router = new window.SprinklesRouter()   
  Backbone.history.start()
```

only the index view of the last router in the list is displayed.  I can rearrange the order of the above list and see the proper contents of the last one displayed in its assigned pane, but only that one. How can I get all 4 to display?

I am in need of some Backbone.js expertise.  Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had multiple routers all chasing a single index function, so the last one that got there won.

I have revised my code using Backbone events and now have all 4 panes displaying properly.